# How to define a vector from iterator recursively

Tags: c++

I am trying to declare in a function a new vector  with the value type from an iterator like the following. If this function is not recursive it is compiling but when the function is calling it self does not compile.

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
auto Foo(ForwardIterator f, ForwardIterator l) {
    typedef typename iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type T;
    auto n = distance(f,l);
    vector<T> v(n);
    auto h = n /2;
    auto m = next(f,h);     
    auto vr = Foo(f,m); // If this line is commented it is compiling
    return v;
}
int main() {
    vector<int> v = { 38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10 };
    auto rv = Foo(v.begin(), v.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be infinite loop anyway.

Comment: The actual error message would help. I guess this is because you can't recursively call a function with a deduced return type.

Comment: g++ 5.1.0: `error: use of 'auto Foo(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator) [with ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]' before deduction of 'auto'` - basically you can't use `foo` before the compiler know what the return type of `foo` is.

Comment: With `-> std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type>`, it compiles... but fails at execution because of infinite recursion.

Comment: fix/cludge: put `if (false) return v;` on the line before `auto vr = Foo(f,m);` - now the compiler knows the return type.  Infinite recursion is now your problem.

Comment: @AndyG: Not exactly, once return type is deduced, you can use `Foo` (so currently after `return v;` but with a early exit it would be before).

Comment: What is your real usage of `vr` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler seems to fail to deduce `auto` type. You could help it to deduce return type by implementing `iterator_type2vector_type` helper class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<typename ForwardIterator>
struct iterator_type2vector_type {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type value_type;
    typedef std::vector<value_type> vector_type;
};

template<typename ForwardIterator>
typename iterator_type2vector_type<ForwardIterator>::vector_type
Foo(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end) {
    typedef typename iterator_type2vector_type<ForwardIterator>::vector_type vector_type;
    // add your code here.
    return vector_type(begin, end);
}


int main() {
    auto a = {1, 2 ,3, 4};
    auto result = Foo(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    std::copy(std::begin(result), std::end(result), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    return 0;
}
```

`auto` return type is *c++14* feature, so with this changes you would go with *c++11*.

Comment: *"auto return type is c++17 feature"*. C++14 in fact. but error is more subtle than that.

Comment: And your return type doesn't match the one from OP's code (surround it by `std::vector<>`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I guess, OP just wants his code to compile. He simplified his code for asking the question on SO, so it falls to infinite recursion.